# How to invert the lengend from Max to Min

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is an example in the web https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/simple_colorbar.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axes-grid1-simple-colorbar-py

I want to invert the legend make it look like this:

[image]

That means the max in the bottom and min in the top in the legend.
making the colorbar "mirrored"

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

ax = plt.subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

# create an axes on the right side of ax. The width of cax will be 5%
# of ax and the padding between cax and ax will be fixed at 0.05 inch.
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you also want the number running 0-100 from top to bottom?

Comment: If you add this option `cmap="viridis_r"` inside `ax.imshow()` you will get the colorbar you want. But the number labels stay the same. Is that OK.

Comment: I hope the number can be 0 to 100 from the top to the bottom. Sorry for my unclear statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `ax` of the colorbar and then call `invert_yaxis()`. This will invert both the colors and the tick labels of the colorbar.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

ax = plt.subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

# create an axes on the right side of ax. The width of cax will be 5%
# of ax and the padding between cax and ax will be fixed at 0.05 inch.
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
cax.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: If the `ax` of the colorbar isn't provided, you can access it as

```py
cbar = plt.colorbar(im)
cbar.ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: of course, you already have the Axes of the colorbar, called `cax` in this example, so could just use that